# Passing JSON in as URL (using Node)

Tags: json, node.js, url, filepath

I am trying to pass a JSON object into the URL to be read by the page to populate it... I am using Node and Grunt.

I have a JSON object in the following location:
    /examples/some-object.json

I want to access it as a URL like so:
    /examples/some-object/

I'm not even sure how to look this problem up to solve it - can anyone give me a starting point?

Comment: So you mean HTTP requests *from the client* for `/examples/some-object/` should hit at `/examples/some-object.json` in your node-based server?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: That's called *URL-rewriting* or *request routing*, depending on where it's done. In a node.js-based application one would call it request routing, and there are many npm modules for it. It depends on the rest of your setup which one is right for you, so you must provide a bit more detail (chances are that this feature is already built into the webserver framework you use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/examples/:name', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('/examples/' + req.params.name + '.json');
});
```